# Null check for destructured variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the below code to create three constants from an object.

```
const {standing_bid_amt, min_increment, starting_price} = props.auction.auction;
```

But the issue here is above constants will be `undefined` if `auction` is an empty object. To fix this, I have changed the code to

```
const {standing_bid_amt, min_increment, starting_price} = props.auction.auction 
  ? props.auction.auction 
  : {standing_bid_amt: null, min_increment:null, starting_price:null};
```

Although it works, I feel maybe this is not the best way to do a null check for the constants. Please do let me know if there is any better way to create the constants with `null` check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the conditional operator, alternate with `{}`, and assign default values (null) to the destructured variables (so that, when the right-hand side of the `=` evaluates to the empty object, `null` gets put into the variables):

```
const {
  standing_bid_amt = null,
  min_increment = null,
  starting_price = null
} = props.auction.auction || {};
```

```js
const doSomething = (props) => {
  const {
    standing_bid_amt = null,
    min_increment = null,
    starting_price = null
  } = props.auction.auction || {};
  console.log(min_increment);
};

doSomething({ auction: {auction: null }});
doSomething({ auction: {auction: {
  standing_bid_amt: 50,
  min_increment: 50,
  starting_price: 50
}}});
```

Comment: If possible, may be you can help me with this question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59259682/null-check-for-destructured-variables-in-object