# Null Check for destructured Variables in object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the code shown below for destructuring `end_time` property from `this.props.auction` object

```
const {auction: {auction: {end_time}}} = this.props;
```

But the issue here is above constant will be undefined if auction is an empty object. To fix this, I have changed the code to

```
if(Object.keys(this.props.auction).length) {
   var {auction: {auction: {end_time}}} = this.props;
} else {
   var {end_time} = "";
}
```

The above solution works but is ugly and I believe there is definitely a far better way of doing it.

Followed the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246166/null-check-for-destructured-variables) and

**My attempt so far is:**

```
const {auction: {auction: {end_time = null}}} = this.props || {};
```

I thought the above one will set `end_time` by default to `null` but I guess since `auction` is not defined it is throwing an error.

Please suggest a better way of declaring the `end_time` constant which takes care of an empty `auction`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don’t need to use destructuring every time you *can* use it.

```
const auction = this.props.auction.auction;
const end_time = auction === undefined ? null : auction.end_time;
```

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The question is open now, so you can add that as a separate answer if you want.

Comment: Thank you. Next time I'll ask if it's okay to edit when I see a wiki answer. I had assumed it was okay to change the answer when it's a wiki, as long as it was still correct and retained the information it started with.

Comment: Thanks @Ry. Makes perfect sense to avoid destructuring. But I was also looking for a solution that shows how to use the default variables with destructuring. I guess the solution from Patrick takes care of that as well.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: It’s totally okay to edit wiki answers like that, but in this case I don’t agree that’s it’s good practice (because it makes more properties optional) and so this is the easiest resolution :P

Comment: @Ry- Although Patricks solution of using destructuring variable also works. May I know which is a better practice while declaring variables? Destructuring with default values or plain declaration with conditional checks?

Comment: @KiranDash hopefully my update should better reflect my opinion on which is better practice. I wrote my answer to demonstrate how you _can_, not to suggest that you _should_.

Comment: @KiranDash: There’s no answer that’s objective or always applicable. Just decide according to your judgement which is more readable and reliable. I opted to recommend this code as written for two reasons: 1) `auction = this.props.auction.auction` looks like less of an accident than `{auction} = this.props.auction` (although getting rid of the repeated name would be ideal if possible), and 2) the optional properties thing – only the existence of `.auction` on `this.props.auction` is in question, so the code reflects that. Optional chaining and equivalents pick up and allow other gaps %

Comment: % along the way, like `.end_time` not existing on `this.props.auction.auction` either.

Comment: @Ry- Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 6):

You could potentially use destructuring with default values like this:

```
const { auction: { auction: { end_time = null } = {} } = {} } = this.props || {};
```

But because the syntax above is cumbersome and unnatural to follow, I ultimately yield to [Ry's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59259712/1541563) in this case:

> You don’t need to use destructuring every time you *can* use it.

---

I realize this is tagged [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6), but this question presents a great example where using the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) seems the most natural solution, at least when they become officially merged into the ECMAScript 2020 specification:

```
const end_time = this.props?.auction?.auction?.end_time ?? null;
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. Answers the question of how to use default values while destructuring.

Answer (score 2):

By combining the use of [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) you can achieve this goal with **only one line** like this:

```
const end_time = props.auction?.auction?.end_time ?? '';
```

Below are few testing functions to understand the concept:

```js
const end_time_defaultValue = 'end_time_defaultValue';

function testWithEndTime() {
    const props = {
        auction: {
            auction: {
            end_time: new Date(),
            kay1: 'value1',
            kay2: 'value2'
            }
        }
    };
    const end_time = props.auction?.auction?.end_time ?? end_time_defaultValue;
    console.log('testWithEndTime() => ', end_time);
}
testWithEndTime();
// outputs the today date

function testWithoutEndTime() {
    const props = {
    auction: {
        auction: {
        kay1: 'value1',
        kay2: 'value2'
        }
    }
    };
    const end_time = props.auction?.auction?.end_time ?? end_time_defaultValue;
    console.log('testWithoutEndTime() => ', end_time);
}
testWithoutEndTime();
// outputs the end_time_defaultValue
// because the key 'end_time' does not exist

function testWithoutAuctionAuction() {
    const props = {
        auction: {

        }
    };
    const end_time = props.auction?.auction?.end_time ?? end_time_defaultValue;
    console.log('testWithoutAuctionAuction() => ', end_time);
}
testWithoutAuctionAuction();
// outputs the end_time_defaultValue
// because the key 'auction.auction' does not exist

function testWithoutPropsAuction() {
    const props = {};;
    const end_time = props.auction?.auction?.end_time ?? end_time_defaultValue;
    console.log('testWithoutPropsAuction() => ', end_time);
}
testWithoutPropsAuction();
// outputs the end_time_defaultValue
// because the key 'props.auction' does not exist
```

**Be careful about browsers compatibility**

[image]

But if you're using a framework like `React`, [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/) will do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may do de-structuring in 2 steps: first de-structure your props, then the necessary object that could be `undefined` at certain point in component life-cycle.

```
// instead of
const {auction: {auction: {end_time}}} = this.props;

// you may do
const { auction } = this.props;
let end_time;
if(auction){
   ({ end_time } = auction);
}
```